# API fetch gets called twice - Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel

I'm fiddling with public imdb-api, but the free version has only 100 api calls available daily. I've noticed my function responsible for fetching data is being called twice. I'm exactly sure why is that. Any tips apprecieated.

ApiService interface

```
interface ApiService {

    /**
     * Get top 250 Movies
     */
    @GET("en/API/Top250Movies/{apiKey}")
    suspend fun getMovies(@Path("apiKey") apiKey : String) : MovieList

    /**
     * Get detailed info about a title with certain ID
     */
    @GET("en/API/Title/{apiKey}/{id}/Ratings,")
    suspend fun getTitleDetailedInfo(@Path("apiKey") apiKey : String, @Path("id") id : String) : Movie
}
```

Repository.class

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService : ApiService,
    @Named("apiKey") private val apiKey : String
    ) : Repository{

    override suspend fun getMovies(): MovieList { // Gets called twice?
        return apiService.getMovies(apiKey)
    }

    override suspend fun getItemDetailedInfo(itemId : String) : Movie { // Gets called twice?
        return apiService.getTitleDetailedInfo(apiKey, itemId)
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.class

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repositoryImpl : RepositoryImpl) : ViewModel() {
    var movieListResponse: List<Movie> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    private var errorMessage: String by mutableStateOf("")

    fun getMovieList(){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            if(movieListResponse.isEmpty()){
                try{
                    val movieList = repositoryImpl.getMovies().items
                    movieListResponse = movieList
                } catch(e : Exception){
                    errorMessage = e.message.toString()
                    Log.d("ErrorMessage", errorMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I call getMovieList() just before displaying a composable. Now that I think of it it might not be the best way to do it.

List composable:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreenNavigationConf(navController : NavHostController){
    val mainViewModel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>()
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = BottomNavigationScreen.TopMovies.route){
        composable(BottomNavigationScreen.TopMovies.route){
            mainViewModel.getMovieList()
            if(mainViewModel.movieListResponse.isEmpty()){
                Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }
            } else{
                MovieListScreen(movieList = mainViewModel.movieListResponse)
            }
        }
        composable(BottomNavigationScreen.TopTvShows.route){
            Text("Test - TV SHOWS")
        }
        composable(BottomNavigationScreen.Search.route){
            Text("Test - SEARCH")
        }
    }
}
```

Detail activity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val detailsViewModel = hiltViewModel<DetailsViewModel>()
            ImdbApiAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val movie = detailsViewModel.movie
                    detailsViewModel.getItemById(movieId)
                    ItemDetailScreen(movie)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is getMoviesList() called?

Comment: Please show the code where getMovieList() is called. Also, note if you are clearing the movieLIst before calling getMovieList()

Comment: I updated the post with the composable in which I run getMovieList()

Comment: I managed to fix it by moving the getMovieList() method to viewmodel init block. However, I still have the same problem with the second fetch function, that is called just right before displaying the screen.